# Added text value disappears when clicking a button in view model

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a textbox and I have a `TextChanged` event:

```
public void tb_textbox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    vm.TextInput = tb_textbox.Text;
}
```

When I debug, it shows that with each input character the TextInput grows as expected. However, when I click a given button to do something with that text, it shows it's null.

The VM and my constructor for the UserControl where the textbox is:

```
UC_VM vm;
public Register()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new UC_VM(this);
    this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

and how the button takes action inside `UC_VM`:

```
public ICommand MyCommand
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

and UC_VM's constructor:

```
public UC_RegVM(UserControl parent)
{
    this.parent = parent;
    MyCommand = new RelayCommand(OnMyClick);
}
```

I'm using GalaSoft's MVVM light to help me with databinding.

Note that I know I should bind this. I just wanted to try this version out as I thought it **should** work, but I have no idea why the `TextInput` property become null when I click that button.

**Edit:**

I have this property inside UC_VM:

```
public string TextInput { get; set; }
```

This gets the input. I get a `NullReferenceException` when I want to access it. In debug it also says it is null, even if I click that button ***after*** I input something inside the textbox.

So when checking from my `.xaml.cs` where that `textbox.textChanged` is using Debug, it's fine. When clicking the Button and checking from UC_VM, it's null.

Comment: Where exactly do you see the `null`? Is it on the screen visually or a specific reference?

Comment: I edit the question right away.

Comment: Is the `TextInput` bound in XAML, or anywhere else have access to `TextInput` it? Have you put a breakpoint on the setter of `TextInput` to see when it is set to null?

Comment: The button is bound in XAML and works. I haven't put that breakpoint there, but I check it out now...

Comment: Strange. It **does** call the setter when I input characters (one by one) but it does **not** when I click the button.

Comment: Sorry, just read again what you said. No, the text prop is **not** bound and has no default valud input.

Comment: How is OnMyClick implemented? Please post *all* relevant parts of your code including the full view model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add vm is null check in textbox_TextCahnged event. Like this:

```
    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (vm != null)
            vm.TextInput = tb_textbox.Text;
    }
```

and it will works fine.